# Transaction RollBack after catching exception

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Is there any way to rollback the transaction after catch the exception using declarative transaction management. I have this piece of code.

```
@Component
@Transactional(rollbackFor = EvictionException.class)
Public class Eviction{

@Autowired
private Alerter alerter;

@Scheduled(cron = "${evictor.cron.expression}")
public void evictObjectFromDatabase(){
try{
   ....
   DO SOME DELETION QUERIES
}catch(Exception ex){
   alerter.produceAlert("Failed to delete entries from database");
}
}
}
```

If a exception is produced while deletion, i need to raise an alert which another team monitors of a swing UI. Also i need to rollback the transaction but using the rollBackFor = Exception.class does not works.

Comment: Where do you throw this `EvictionException` which is marked with `@Transactional` for a rollback?

Comment: Can you throw the exception out of the method using throws or that's not an option?

Comment: Is There any way that i can rollback the transaction withour re-throwing exception

Answer (score 7):

You need to annotate your method with `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` and in catch block throw the exception(So that transactional proxy can detect the exception and Hence rollback) E.g.

```
try{
   ....
   DO SOME DELETION QUERIES
}catch(Exception ex){
   alerter.produceAlert("Failed to delete entries from database");
   throw ex;// this is important
}
```

Comment: Tnx for your inputs 1 more thing i want to know is like if i throw an exception from here it will be logged in my log file. If many such exceptions occur it will fill up my logs, is there any workaround for this such that my exception is not logged in my log file

Comment: I tries annotating with @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) and using throw ex. It revert my transaction.

I then tried without @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) and USING throw ex, It also reverts my transaction. So what is the point of using rollbackFor ?? confused here :(

Comment: @AmbujJauhari The difference is if you throw your custom exception for e.g. `throw new FooException()` then ONLY `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` will work because spring transaction rollback follows EJB Conventation

Comment: @AmbujJauhari You can create your own custom exception and  use it in throw clause, then you can configure your logging framework to log those exception in different log file OR if you don't want to log anything then may be configure your logging framework to exclude them from logging but personally I would prefer first approach logging exception to separate file.

Comment: @solme  The difference is if you throw your custom exception for e.g. throw new FooException() then ONLY @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) will work because spring transaction rollback follows EJB Conventation .This is partially correct .If your customer exception extend from exception then you have to provide the rollback attribute but if it extends from runtime exception and you are throwing it from catch block then there is no need to provide rollbackfor attribute

Answer (score 0):

@Ambuj Jauhari if you look into the documentation of @transactional the roll back occurs either for error or runtime exception.Most probably in your case roll back is happening when you are not providing rollback for exception .class because exception being thrown is of runtime exception and not any checked exception.If the type of exception thrown had been any checked exception then roll back wouldn't have happened if you wouldn't have provided rollback for exception.class attribute

Answer (score -1):

use SqlTransaction and RollBack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).